# Tomcat connection pooling method

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am developing a J2EE application which will receive requests from a mobile application and does some database operations to show the data to the user.

So database connection pooling is of great importance to me.I declared `context.xml` in my **META-INF** folder of my J2EE application.It looks as follows

```
<Context debug="0"
    reloadable="true" crossContext="false" privileged="true" cookies="true" >
    
     <Resource name="jdbc/servicedb" 
               auth="Container"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
               driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
               username="XXXXXX"
               password="XXXXXX"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX:XXXXXXX"
               initialSize="10"
               maxActive="100"
               maxIdle="50"
               minIdle="10"
               suspectTimeout="60"
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"/>
</Context>
```

And this is a method from my connection class which returns a connection

```
public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        
        //loading from the dao.properties file
        DAOProperties properties = new DAOProperties("com.jndi");
        String url = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_URL, true);
        String driverClassName = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_DRIVER, false);
        String password = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_PASSWORD, false);
        String username = properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_USERNAME, password != null);
        
     // If driver is specified, then load it to let it register itself with DriverManager.
        if(driverClassName !=null){
            try
            {
                Class.forName(driverClassName);
                dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                // Could not find the database driver
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("database driver error");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     // Else assume URL as DataSource URL and lookup it in the JNDI.
        else{
            Context initContext;
            DataSource ds;
            try {
                initContext = new InitialContext();
                Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup(JNDI_ROOT);
                if(envContext!=null){
                    ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(url);
                    if(ds!=null){
                        try {
                            dbConnection = ds.getConnection();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }
```

DAOProperties is a wrapper class for loading the Properties file.I took it from [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

I am closing the connection like this

```
public static void close(Connection connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Closing Connection failed: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally i am using the connection to polulate a list like this

```
public loadlist(){
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try{
            dbConnection = Connection.getConnection();
        if(dbConnection !=null){
                
            System.out.println("Connected to database");
            LOGGER.debug("Successfully connected to database");
        else{
                System.out.println("No Connection Exists");
                LOGGER.debug("unable to connect to database");
        }
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            // Could not connect to the database
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("database connection failed");
            LOGGER.debug("database connection failed due to SQLException");
        }finally{
            Connection.close(dbConnection);
            LOGGER.debug("connection closed");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Just now i have gone through [this](http://webdevelopersjournal.com/columns/connection_pool.html) on connection pooling.

I have an doubt whether i can close my connection or return it to the pool?

I also want to know how to return a connection to the pool?

Please help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your code takes the *else* path in the `getConnection()` method (i.e. it does a JNDI lookup instead of using the *DriverManager*), your use of the connection pool is correct.

You cannot choose between closing a connection and returning it to the pool. If you got the connection from the pool, `close()` will return it to the pool (instead of closing it). There's no other option. You can only close connection that you have created yourself.

Comment: In other words: handle a `Connection` from a pool the same way you'd handle a non-pooled connection: simply call `close()` when you're done using it.

Comment: @Codo-Thanks for the response.What you are saying is tomcat only will take care of managing the connections.Just see the `close` method [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html#HowAboutConnectionPooling)

Comment: @Sreeram: The `close()` method linked in your comment is an illustration how the connection pool is implemented and not how you should use it or or how you should implement your DAO classes. Tomcat manages when to create connection, when to reuse connection, when to return a connection to the pool and when to close it.

Comment: Not 100% sure but in the docs this is the way to get the actual connection, closing this may completely close the connection. `Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
Connection actual = ((javax.sql.PooledConnection)con).getConnection();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd write your own connection pool.

I'd recommend scrapping this approach and going with JNDI data sources, managed by Tomcat, and a pool written by someone else.  Apache has a good DBCP - why write your own?

Comment: @duffymo-Thanks for the response.I am now following JNDI lookup approach only.My doubt is regarding the returning the connection to the pool in the `close` method.